# How to deal size classes with a View Model in iOS Applications?

Tags: ios, mvvm, viewmodel, size-classes, uitraitcollection

I was wondering how to properly deal the size classes in my iOS app. I had 2 different designs.

Should this be managed in the view controller or the view model? Do I need to embed the Trait collection in the viewModel?

Comment: you can use AutoLayout, and play around with constraints. You can also build everything by using code, and just override `didLayoutSubviews` everywhere to return the right sizes based on some boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Basically a UIViewController is View in MVVM. The ViewModel do not need to know anything about size class, because it is not defining the layout. The View does. It is the same as text color. You set color in a View not in a ViewModel.

Comment: But, If I need to show a string with a format depending on the size class, should that be placed in the UIViewController, how can I test that code?

Comment: For example you can make class Formatter and tests for it. In `UIViewController` you can just use it.

Comment: Another example, if I need to show a collection with different cell and section depending on the Size Class. Should this be controlled by the view controller, and only ask ViewModel for data? Is it correct to make unit test of code related to Size Classes?